# Nest JS / MongoDB - geospatial index not working on deployed server

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nestjs

I'm writing an API in NestJS which fetches data stored in a MongoDB database and uses GraphQL to return it. It's supposed to fetch `Devices` with an attribute called `location` - a GeoJSON point. There's also a `2dsphere` index on it, which allows searching for `Devices` in a circle using `$geoNear` query. Everything works fine on a local machine, but when the API is deployed on a server, querying for `Devices` in a circle returns no records, despite records and the index being present.

Search query looks like this:

```js
  const location = [input.center.lng, input.center.lat]

  return [
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: location
        },
        distanceField: 'distance',
        maxDistance: input.radius,
        key: 'location'
      }
    }
  ]
```

DevicesService using this pipeline:

The database is deployed using Kubernetes. Here's the config:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: v3-ds-mongo
  name: v3-ds-mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: v3-ds-mongo
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: v3-ds-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: root
          image: mongo:latest
          name: v3-ds-mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: v3-ds-mongo-claim0
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: v3-ds-mongo-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: v3-ds-mongo-claim0
status: {}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The index should be also created on the server, you can do this manually but not efficient, however you could create an initialization file for the database to define the index:

```
connection = new Mongo();

db = connection.getDB("database_name")

db.users.createIndex({ location: '2dsphere' })
```

And reference the file in your config